# Alternatives to Google Scholar for citation / lit search / BibTex entries?

Tags: citations, literature-review, literature-search, latex, bibtex

**Simple question:** What alternatives are there to Google Scholar for finding citations, doing lit searches, and most importantly, downloading citation data in BibTex?

There are lots of specialized databases (e.g. MathSciNet, ACM, etc.), but I am not aware of any that index across all disciplines the way Google Scholar does. My research is quite multidisciplinary so these specialized databases are usually insufficient.

Comment: Go ask your friendly local research librarian - this is the sort of thing they love to help you with. And they know what is available through the institution, which may include some highly specialized databases to mix with more general ones.

Answer (score 4):

Paid options: [Scopus](http://scopus.com) ([bibtex export](https://libguides.usask.ca/c.php?g=218034&p=1445629)) and [Web of Science](http://webofscience.com) ([bibtex export](https://libguides.usask.ca/c.php?g=218034&p=1445132))

Free option: [Microsoft Academic Search](http://academic.microsoft.com) ([bibtex export](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/research/project/academic/articles/new-feature-citation-list/)).

Answer (score 1):

I use Mendeley which offers a literature search function and stores my entire library of papers as a BibTex file.